# How to put an item in center in one component on two different screen in React Native?

Tags: css, react-native, react-component

I have a custom component named ProfileImagePicker and I use it on two different screens.
on one screen it works perfectly fine
as shown here.
[image]

but on other screen it does not align work fine[image]

so how do I fix this?

Styles for this component

```
  container: {
    backgroundColor: colors.lightGrey,
    borderRadius: 25,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    overflow: "hidden",
  },
  image: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  },
});
```

Comment: can't see second image properly can u plz upload another?

Comment: Well There is not something big just the camera Icon is at the top..

Comment: By the way I have fixed the error. I mistakenly wrote styles for such behaviour.